# C++ using std::sscanf and std::string

Tags: c++, string, scanf

I am wanting to "extract" the info from a string. The string is always in the format `int int char`.

I have spent solid hours on this, checked "every" example this site and google I found, to no avail. Some examples compiled, but crashed (no overflow.)

Here is the current, it compiles but crashes.

```
// Data                    
string str = "53 25 S";
int num1;
int num2;
char type3;

// Read values                                  
sscanf(str.c_str(),"%i %i %c",num1,num2,type3);
```

Comment: Is `std::istringstream` a consideration?

Comment: Yeah. and there was the strtok() consideration, but for this I wanted as simple as it could be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the address of operator i.e.

```
sscanf(str.c_str(),"%i %i %c",&num1,&num2,&type3);
```

Answer (score 10):

The documentation for `sscanf()` should contain the answer to your question.

If you really insist on using `sscanf()`, then the addresses of `num1`, `num2`, and `num3` need to be passed, not their values.

```
sscanf(str.c_str(),"%i %i %c",&num1,&num2,&type3);
```

You would be better off using a `stringstream` (declared in standard header `<sstream>`) than trying to use deprecated functions from C.

```
std::istringstream some_stream(str);
some_stream >> num1 >> num2 >> type3;
```

Comment: It'd be nice to include a link re how to use stringstream for people who know the sscanf way. Like how to translate a general format string into the stringstream paradigm.

Comment: There's not really any such link, except for quite simple/trivial cases [like this question].  They are said to involve different *paradigms* because they involve quite different ways of thinking about the underlying problem (how to extract specified information from a string).